# Accessing Local file from a browser?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, internet-explorer, activex

Hi I want to access a local file of my system from the browser? Is there anyway through which it can be achieved as there are lot of security checks invloved? or any other work arround using ActiveX or Java Applet???? Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a local file through your browser, you can use a signed Java Applet. Through [JFileChooser](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) you can ask the user for a file, and if the applet is signed and you have configured properly the security of your applet, this will work.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) is the sun page on signing an applet.

Comment: How to sign the applet? please can you help me in this regard..??

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript won't work but you can use flash, ActiveX or a signed Java applet.

Answer (score 0):

From 6u10, unsigned Java applets can load and save files through a file chooser using the [JNLP service APIs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/package-summary.html).