# Javascript accessing a local file on computer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, localhost

is there a way to allow a domain access a file which is stored on my computer?

I wish to inject javascript a  tag into a website, with the source as a file stored on my computer. This works within a local test.html page, but not when trying to run the script on an actual domain.

Is there a way to set this up my changing window's host file?

**Edit - it MUST work in IE**
Clarification :: I wish to use javascript injection (using the javascript: protocol) to manipulate the DOM within IE, this is fine. There is however an 8k byte limit within the address bar, which isn't enough. Therefore I wish to store it within a local file on my computer.

Comment: Did you bother to see/check the links prompted when you were posting this question? Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431643/accessing-local-file-from-a-browser

Comment: @Cybernate I don't want a filechooser, I just want to get access to it automatically as a pure javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing it on your computer you could store it online and then load the Javascript through a much smaller amount of code in the address bar.

It's explained how to do this here

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: that's pretty much what i'm asking, how to make IE think a local file is being accessed from a non 'file://' protocol. All i can think of is creating a web server locally really

Comment: yeah I imagine that'd be the easiest thing to do. Save a lot of hassle

Answer (score 0):

Try the file API  if you're on a recent browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_files_from_web_applications

If not and you're on IE, you should be able to do it with ActiveX but it'll always ask for permission.

Comment: Updated original question. ActiveX has problems in IE9 when I tried it.

Comment: I've clarified again within my host, that should make it clearer