# Save form data to text file - HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not worried about security, this is just a small project, which I am using only on my computer. I need to store a .txt file with data from a login form to the same location that the HTML file is. I don't think you can do it with javascript, but I don't know anything about PHP and I have tried many times to get this to work, but it isn't. Here is my code.

```html
<form style="text-align: center;" action="./success.html" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
  </div>
  <input id="button1" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
  <!-- When pressed, needs to store data in a data.txt file. -->
</form>
```

How would I be able to do this if I'm using this setup, and what would I need to change?

Comment: Why the PHP tag, you want to store your txt file in  a server ?

Comment: I thought It was only possible to store data in php. I removed the tag

Comment: I do not understand. why specifically store login data which I imagine is used to access a server?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I meant create an account. When the user actually logs in, it reads the data. I copied the wrong part of code. Let me fix that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Local file from a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431643/accessing-local-file-from-a-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just show you a quick example to get you started and create a JSON file with some data like:

```json
{"username":"Lorem", "password":"ipsum"}
```

[image]

- Rather than into `.txt` use a `.json` file. It's the today's most popular standard for  storage and transmit of structured data.
- Use AJAX to send a request and receive a response - **without page refresh**
- Use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the nifty PHP's `file_put_content`
- Use JS's `fetch` ("POST") with the data being the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Run the demo using `php -S localhost:81` and open it in your [browser](http://localhost:81):

`save.php`

```php
<?php
if (
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'
    && isset($_POST["username"])
    && isset($_POST["password"])
) {
    $json = json_encode($_POST);
    // Save JSON to file
    file_put_contents("user.json", $json);
    // Return some data back to the AJAX request.
    echo $json;
    // PS it's not wise to send passwords that way. 
}
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#!" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>AJAX PHP - SAVE USER DATA </title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>User: <span data-username>Unknown</span></h1>

    <form id="form-login" action="./save.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                <span>Username</span>
                <input placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="username">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>
                <span>Password</span>
                <input placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" type="password" name="password">
            </label>
        </div>
        <input id="button1" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>

    <script>
        const EL_formLogin = document.querySelector("#form-login");
        EL_formLogin.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault(); // Stop default form submit - we'll use AJAX
            fetch(EL_formLogin.action, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: new FormData(EL_formLogin),
            }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
                // Hide the form
                EL_formLogin.hidden = true;
                // Show the user name
                document.querySelector("[data-username]").textContent = data.username;
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**DISCLAIMER!**

Never store passwords in plaintext on your server files or database - and only send passwords over HTTPS.